# Default result in struts2

Tags: struts2, action

Im wondering if it's possible to set a default result that would apply to every action in struts2.

For example to say that result "FOO" will always redirect to action BAR or to jsp "BAR.jsp" instead of adding `<result name="FOO">xxx</result>` to every action I define ...

That would help me to create a generic error page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution that comes to my mind is global result configuration.Most often, results are nested with the action element. But some results apply to multiple actions. In a secure application, a client might try to access a page without being authorized, and many actions may need access to a "logon" result.

If actions need to share results, a set of global results can be defined for each package. The framework will first look for a local result nested in the action. If a local match is not found, then the global results are checked.

```
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="invalid.token">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="login" type="redirectAction">Logon!input</result>
</global-results>
```

For more details refer to the official doc

- [result-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/result-configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set global results for a package.

```
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="invalid.token">/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="login" type="redirectAction">Logon!input</result>
</global-results>
```

For more details read [Result Configuration Page](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/result-configuration.html)